# access leaves of json tree

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a JSON file of the form:

```
{"id":442500000116137984, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":442502378957201408, "reply":0, "children":[]}]}
{"id":442500001084612608, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":442500145871990784, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":442500258421952512, "reply":1, "children":[]}]}]}
{"id":442500000258342912, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":442500636668489728, "reply":0, "children":[]}]}
```

In this each line refers to a separate tree. Now I want to go to the leaves of every tree and do something, basically

```
import json
f = open("file", 'r')
for line in f:
    tree = json.loads(line)
    #somehow walk through the tree and find leaves
    if isLeaf(child):
        print "Reached Leaf"
```

How do I walk through this tree object to detect all leaves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
import json
f = open("file", 'r')

leafArray = []

def parseTree(obj):
    if len(obj["children"]) == 0:
        leafArray.append(obj)
    else:
        for child in obj["children"]:
            parseTree(child)

for line in f:
    global leafArray
    leafArray = []
    tree = json.loads(line.strip())
    parseTree(tree) 
    #somehow walk through the tree and find leaves
    print ""
    for each in leafArray:
        print each
```

Answer (score 2):

You know, I once had to deal with a lot of hypermedia objects out of JSON, so I wrote [this library](https://github.com/pellagic-puffbomb/pelecanus). The problem was that I didn't know the depths of the trees beforehand, so I needed to be able to search around and get what I called the "paths" (the set of keys/indices you would use to reach a leaf) and values.

Anyway, you can mine it for ideas (I wrote it only for Python3.3+, but [here's the method inside a class that would do what you want](https://github.com/pellagic-puffbomb/pelecanus/blob/master/pelecanus/pelicanjson.py#L158)).

The basic idea is that you walk down the tree and check the objects you encounter and if you get more dictionaries (even inside of lists), you keep plunging deeper (I found it easier to write it as a recursive generator mostly by subclassing `collections.MutableMapping` and creating a class with a custom `enumerate`).

You keep track of the path you've taken along the way and once you get a value that doesn't merit further exploration (it's not a `dict` or a `list`), then you yield your path and the value:

```
def enumerate(self, path=None):
    """Iterate through the PelicanJson object yielding 1) the full path to
    each value and 2) the value itself at that path.
    """
    if path is None:
    path = []
    for k, v in self.store.items():
        current_path = path[:]
        current_path.append(k)

        if isinstance(v, PelicanJson):
            yield from v.enumerate(path=current_path)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for idx, list_item in enumerate(v):
                list_path = current_path[:]
                list_path.append(idx)
                if isinstance(list_item, PelicanJson):
                    yield from list_item.enumerate(path=list_path)
                else:
                    yield list_path, list_item
        else:
            yield current_path, v
```

Because this is exclusively for Python3, it takes advantage of things like `yield from`, so it won't work out of the box for you (and I certainly don't mean to offer my solution as the only one). Personally, I just got frustrated with reusing a lot of this logic in various functions, so writing this library saved me a lot of work and I could go back to doing weird things with the Hypermedia APIs I had to deal with.

---

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this. (I don't know the syntax of python).

```
temp = tree #Your JSON object in each line
while (temp.children ! = []){
    temp = temp.children;
}
```

Your temp will now be the leaf.

Comment: thanks, but i was really looking for an answer in python.. since i am a python noob myself