# Get all leaf nodes of a Json file using JsonPath

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I am looking for a JsonPath expression to retrieve all leaf nodes of a Json file using python.

I used to work with XML using the xPath expression `//*[not(child::*)]`

I am wondering if any equivalent expression exists.

Thanks

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051024/access-leaves-of-json-tree)?

Comment: While this will probably solve the OPs problem, the question asks specifically for a solution using JsonPath.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, i was hpoing jsonpath would help but it looks like it easier to just manually parse the json tree.